# JS file array javascript in html page to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a js file that contains two columns of data. Col 1 has hexadecimal code for a colour and col 2 has the name of the colour (of that code):

```
// JavaScript Document
/*Below lists the hex and equiv colour.
*/
var mycolors = {
"000000": "Black",
"000080": "Navy Blue",
"0000C8": "Dark Blue",
"0000FF": "Blue",
"000741": "Stratos",
"001B1C": "Swamp",
```

In my html web page I have a colour picker that generates the hexadecimal value of any colour clicked.

I want to be able to use that hex number to look up the external js file in col1 and return the colour name from col2.

My experience of all things web is limited and googleing and trial and error has failed.

Can anyone provide an example of how this can be done?

```
<div class="paletteandbox">
    <div class="palette">
     <canvas width="234" height="199" id="canvas_picker"></canvas> </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_picker').getContext('2d');
    // create an image object and get it’s source
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = 'picker3hexagon.gif';
    // copy the image to the canvas
                $(img).load(function(){
                canvas.drawImage(img,0,0);
                }); <!-- OK -->

    // http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm
                function rgbToHex(R,G,B) {return toHex(R)+toHex(G)+toHex(B)}
                function toHex(n) {
                n = parseInt(n,10);
                if (isNaN(n)) return "00";
                n = Math.max(0,Math.min(n,255));
                return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n-n%16)/16)  + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n%16);
                }
    $('#canvas_picker').click(function(event){
      // getting user coordinates
      var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      // getting image data and RGB values
      var img_data = canvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;<!-- OK -->
      var R = img_data[0];
      var G = img_data[1];
      var B = img_data[2];  var rgb = R + ',' + G + ',' + B;
      // convert RGB to HEX
      var hex = rgbToHex(R,G,B);
      // making the color the value of the input
      $('#rgb input').val(rgb);
      $('#hex input').val('#' + hex);
      $("#path3349").css("fill", "#" + hex); 
      $('#hex').val('#' + hex);   
    });
</script>
</div>
<!-- palette-->
<div class="box">
<script src="colourpicker.js">
var colorhex = hex
var colorname = mycolors[colorhex];
</script> 
     Selected Background Colour:
     <div id="colorname"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" /></input></div>
     Background Colour Codes:
     <div id="hex"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" /></input>HEX</div>
     <div id="rgb"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" /></input>RGB</div>
</div> <!-- box-->
</div> <!-- palette and box-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed it slightly since your code wasn't working, but it will give you an idea of how to look it up from your object and work with it.

- The portion you need is:
  var englishColorName = mycolors[key]

where key is your hex value. So you look in your object at key with that hex value.

The fact that your object is defined in an external js file is irrelevant as long as it's loaded before this code it will run the same.

```js
var mycolors = {
  "000000": "Black",
  "000080": "Navy Blue",
  "0000C8": "Dark Blue",
  "0000FF": "Blue",
  "000741": "Stratos",
  "001B1C": "Swamp"
}

for (var key in mycolors) {
  //console.log("Key: ", key);
  //console.log("Color: ", mycolors[key]);

  $('#colorsSelect')
    .append($("<option></option>")
      .attr("value", key)
      .text(mycolors[key]));
}

var colorhex = hex
var colorname = mycolors[colorhex];


// http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm
function rgbToHex(R, G, B) {
  return toHex(R) + toHex(G) + toHex(B)
}

function convertHex(hex){
    hex = hex.replace('#','');
    r = parseInt(hex.substring(0,2), 16);
    g = parseInt(hex.substring(2,4), 16);
    b = parseInt(hex.substring(4,6), 16);

    result = 'rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
    return result;
}

function toHex(n) {
  n = parseInt(n, 10);
  if (isNaN(n)) return "00";
  n = Math.max(0, Math.min(n, 255));
  return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n - n % 16) / 16) + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n % 16);
}

$( "#colorsSelect" ).change(function() {
  var hex = $( this ).val();
  var rgb = convertHex(hex);
  $('#hex input').val('#' + hex);
  $('#rgb input').val(rgb);
});

/*
$('#canvas_picker').click(function(event) {
  // getting user coordinates
  var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  // getting image data and RGB values
  var img_data = canvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data; <!-- OK -->
  var R = img_data[0];
  var G = img_data[1];
  var B = img_data[2];
  var rgb = R + ',' + G + ',' + B;
  // convert RGB to HEX
  var hex = rgbToHex(R, G, B);
  // making the color the value of the input
  $('#rgb input').val(rgb);
  $('#hex input').val('#' + hex);
  $("#path3349").css("fill", "#" + hex);
  $('#hex').val('#' + hex);
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paletteandbox">
  <div class="palette">
    <canvas width="234" height="199" id="canvas_picker"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- palette-->
<div class="box">
  Selected Background Colour:

  <select id="colorsSelect">
    <option value="-1">--Select a color--</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <br>Converted Background Colour Codes:
  <div id="hex">
    HEX:
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
  </div>
  <div id="rgb">
    RGB:
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
  </div>
  <!-- box-->
</div>
<!-- palette and box-->
```